# How to remove desktop icons from terminal?

Tags: 13.10, icons, .desktop

How do I remove desktop icons from the terminal?

It may seem easier to do it with the mouse but it is not practical for my needs, so I'm looking for a way to do it via the terminal.

Comment: Which Desktop Environnement are you using (Unity, Gnome, XFCE, ...)?

Comment: ubuntu saucy amd64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**.desktop files :** 
a shortcut.desktop file is a text-file placed in the Desktop directory (~/Desktop) that is used to provide clickable shortcuts on the Desktop.

1. Check which ".desktop" files are used in your desktop :

   `ls ~/Desktop`
2. Identify the ".desktop" you want to remove.
3. Remove the ".desktop" file you want to remove (replace *nameofthefile* by the name of the file, ending with *.desktop*):

   `rm ~/Desktop/nameofthefile.desktop`

---

**D-conf keys :** it's a key stored in d-conf that is used to provide clickable shortcuts on the Unity Launcher bar.

1. Get the list of launcher items:

   `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites`
2. This will return something like `['nautilus-home.desktop', 'gnome-terminal.desktop', 'gedit.desktop']` which you can manipulate to remove unwanted shortcuts.
3. Set the launcher item list with only the launcher you want, *example*:

   `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['nautilus-home.desktop']"`

Don't forget the quotes !

Answer (score 2):

The easiest was would be to use the `dconf-editor` and remove the unwanted apps from the *desktop->unity->launcher->favorites* section.